# Subset is inconsistent within Loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, subset

I use subset daily, but recently encountered a problem when I tried to subset within a loop using an indexed vector to specify the subset conditions.  See example below, where the factor does not correctly subset?

I tried forcing it to be a factor as well with no luck.  I'm sure this is an issue on my end, not that subset is buggy.  I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
   ##make df

    df<-data.frame(factor=c("red","green","green","blue"), Numeric=c(1:3,3))


    ## subset by numeric
    Numeric<-unique(df$Numeric)

    for(i in 1:length(Numeric)){
    print(subset(df, Numeric==Numeric[i]))
    }

  ##this works as expected
      factor Numeric
1    red       1
  factor Numeric
2  green       2
  factor Numeric
3  green       3
4   blue       3

    ## subset by facor
    factor<-unique(df$factor)

    for(j in 1:length(factor)){
      print(subset(df, factor==factor[[j]]))
    }

##This runs, but fails, green is subsetted twice and blue is missed
  factor Numeric
1    red       1
  factor Numeric
2  green       2
3  green       3
  factor Numeric
2  green       2
3  green       3
```

Comment: That kind of notation inside subset (indexing inside subset) can be unstable. I'm personally not sure as to why. I think you're just better off using standard data frame notation, for the first case: `print(df[df$Numeric == df$Numeric[i], ])` Someone else might be able to speak to why this is buggy or have a different solution.

Comment: Imagine for a moment that you are just a computer, which is to say not nearly as smart as a human. In your second example, imagine how confusing it must be for the silly, dumb computer to figure out what each `factor` refers to. There is a function by that name, there is a column in your data frame by that name _and_ there's a stand alone vector with that name. So confusing! `subset` is trying to do something very complicated to make your life easy (resolve names to reduce typing) and you've gone out of your way to make it's job very very hard! ;)

Comment: ...which was a long way of saying, use some name other than `factor`, don't use the same name twice, and even better, don't use `subset` except when working interactively at the command line.

Comment: In this case it would be better to work with `split(df, df$factor)`. Both help pages for `subset` and `with` have warnings that they should only be used outside functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @42- and I may simply not be communicating well, so for clarity's sake what I was referring to in my comments was that simply changing the second example as follows:

```
> f<-unique(df$factor)
> f
[1] red   green blue 
Levels: blue green red

> for(j in 1:length(f)){
+   print(subset(df, factor==f[j]))
+ }
  factor Numeric
1    red       1
  factor Numeric
2  green       2
3  green       3
  factor Numeric
4   blue       3
```

appears to yield the correct result, hence my conclusion that `subset` is finding the wrong `factor`.

Comment: I see that result, but it's not the same as I am getting (despite the fact that my example in my comment was not correct.) When I use the name `non_factor` (consistently) I get a different result and when I use the name 'f' I get empty datasets.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it has anything to do with the name 'factor'. See these instances where it succeeds as expected:

```
 for(j in unique(df$factor) ){
   print(subset(df, factor==j))
 }
#-----
  factor Numeric
1    red       1
  factor Numeric
2  green       2
3  green       3
  factor Numeric
4   blue       3

 for(j in factor ){
   print(subset(df, factor==j))
 }
#------
  factor Numeric
1    red       1
  factor Numeric
2  green       2
3  green       3
  factor Numeric
4   blue       3
```

The first example would obviate the need for an external object by the admitted unwise name "factor". The help page's warning clearly applies to its use within `for`-loops which are functions after all.

Comment: I based my comment partially on the fact that when I changed the vector factor to be called just f it worked fine.

Comment: When I re-ran the code with the name factor changed to 'non_factor', I got a different result, but still not a correct one: To wit ...  `df<-data.frame(non_factor=c("red","green","green","blue"), Numeric=c(1:3,3)); Numeric<-unique(df$Numeric)
non_factor<-unique(df$non_factor);
for(j in 1:length(factor)){
  print(subset(df, factor==factor[[j]]))
}`

Comment: Thanks Folks,  Yes, @joran, you are correct in that the name of the column, and the name of the vector you are calling from can not have the same name or else the result is erroneous.  What a funny bug...

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help.  I find this bug to be a little concerning, easy to miss that the subset is not working properly, especially on big datasets.

Comment: @ctlamb Keep in mind that the docs explicitly warn against using `subset` except as a convenience function interactively, and that the `subset` argument will be evaluated in the data frame, so it's behaving as documented.